# match words in a string

Tags: regex

I have the next code:

```
$string = "hello to all world";
$strings_compare = tomorrow, hello, world;
$string_arrays =split(',',$strings_compare);

      for ($i=0; $i<count($string_arrays); $i++){
          $resultado = preg_match("/$string_arrays[$i]/",$string);
             if($resultado == false){   
             echo "no match";              
             }else {
            echo "match";
             }
      }
```

in this code the results are:
no match, match, no match

and the results should be: no match, match and match.  What is my error?

if I change the `$string` by `$string='say hello to all world now'`
the results are match, match, match, this is OK.

Comment: array() not ()... `array("tomorrow", "hello", "world")`. also, change `preg_match("/$string_arrays[$i]/",$string);` to `preg_match("/".{$string_arrays[$i]}."/",$string);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine for me when I'm using valid array syntax.

```
<?php
$string = "hello to all world";
$string_arrays = array("tomorrow", "hello", "world");

for ($i=0; $i<count($string_arrays); $i++) {
    $resultado = preg_match("/$string_arrays[$i]/",$string);
    if(!$resultado) {   
        echo "no match";              
    } else {
        echo "match";
    }
}
```

Returns

> no matchmatchmatch

Comment: You have right, the preg_match function is not the error, but why is my error in this:  $strings_compare = tomorrow, hello, world;
$string_arrays =split(',',$strings_compare);???  I can't see it.

Comment: ok, thanks very much.  Your help is very useful for me.  I will review how can I convert $string_arrays in array, thanks again.

Comment: Finally, this is my code:  $strings_compare = tomorrow, hello, world; $string_arrays =explode(',',$strings_compare); and in the bucle for I deleted the spaces in white $string_arrays[$i]=trim($string_arrays[$i]); and works now for me.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$resultado = preg_match("/".preg_quote($string_arrays[$i])."/",$string);
```

Also:

```
$string_arrays = array("tomorrow", "hello", "world");
```